# How to get id of selected table whose id is dynamic and unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have situation where my tables are dynamically generated with ids. Now i can generate two tables within same page and i need to manipulate these tables using their unknown ids. For example. Insert row button is available which when clicked should add row to selected table given there maybe more than one table on the page. How can i achieve this through javascript. This is what i have done so far:

please note the ids of the tables are dynamically generated so they are not known. I want to get id of table two whenever i click anywhere on the table.

The issue with my code is e.target.id gets id of any element clicked on the page and not necessarily the table. Its only if i click on the table head that the table id is gotten. But if i click inside the table the row id is chosen instead of the parent table id.

```js
function RealClickHandler() {
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
  }, false);
  return id;
}
function insertrow() {
  var tableid = RealClickHandler();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="insertrow">Add row</button>


<table id="ABC">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="EFD">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Dynamic IDs are an anti-pattern.   You don't need the ID.   You relative DOM navigation instead.  eg put both the button and the table in a single div with a class, then `$(this).closest(".wrapper").find("table")`  (where `this` is the button in the event handler (or `e.target` if not using jquery))

Comment: The table is generated onclicking a button and many tables can be generated from the button. There is a standard table setting on top where users can click to add rows, columns, merge rows to selected table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code will not return the ID in the function RealClickHandler because that is not how event handling works. It will be the assigned click event handler itself that returns the id, not the function that assigns the event handler

You can use closest to get the table from a click on the table content

So my code needs the user to click the table before clicking the add button

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const insertRow = (tbody) => tbody.append(tbody.querySelector("tr").cloneNode(true))
  let currentTable;
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("table");
    if (!tgt) return; // it was not a table
    if (currentTable) currentTable.classList.remove("active");
    currentTable = tgt;
    currentTable.classList.add("active");
    console.log(currentTable.id); // actually not needed anymore
  });
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentTable) insertRow(currentTable.querySelector('tbody')); // for example
    else console.log("nothing selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">Add row</button>
<table id="ABC">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<table id="DEF">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that did not work.

Comment: I had `table` instead of `tgt` - it works now

Comment: our code is explicit but it will get the table closest to the button to insert row to. Now i may have a table below the first table which is where i want to add the row and this is not close to the button. Clicking the insert button above will not affect this table. Please tell me what to do in such a situation

Comment: I have added some code with description of what i am looking for

Comment: Ok, Click a table and then add row

Comment: Your code now seems to work as i expect

Comment: "*the table closest to the button*"/"*this is not close to the button*" - note that javascript/jquery have a specific meaning for `closest` and it's "closest *parent*" - not the closest x/y on the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m OP wants to select the table to add a row to by clicking anywhere in the table. Then a click on the button will add to the clicked/selected table. I also initially did not get that. My code will add to the selected table when the single button is clicked

Comment: @mplungjan no worries - you had it sorted - just highlighting the term `closest` vs "close to"

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `selected` class to a table when it's selected and search for such a table that has such a class when the button is clicked. Of course, you will need to handle the case when no table was selected yet, or a table is selected (both in the case when no previous table was selected and when a previous table was selected). I've styled the selected table with lightgreen background to clarify the flow visually.

```js
function insertrow() {
  let selected = document.querySelector("table.selected");
  if (!selected) alert("Select a table first!");
  else {
      selected.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML += "<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>";
  }
}

for (let table of document.querySelectorAll("table")) {
    table.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let selected = document.querySelector("table.selected");
        if (selected) selected.classList.remove("selected");
        this.classList.add("selected");
    });
}
```

```css
table.selected {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="insertrow()">Add row</button>


<table id="ABC">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="EFD">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```